# Memory consumption discrepancy with TUN interface

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I was experimenting with TUN interface multi_queue functionality.
It works well and traffic gets distributed to different queues, giving my application better performance.

However, I also noticed that simply creating the TUN interface using tuntap command with multi_queue makes kernel consume GBs of memory more compared to the scenario when interface is created using tuptap command without multi_queue set.

I tested this on Ubuntu 20, running kernel 5.4.0-94-generic and for about 1200 TUN interface, the system ate up to 30GB of memory vs 0.3GB when 1200 TUN interfaces without multi_queue.

My test was simple, run vmstat to monitor free memory and create 1200 TUN interface via a script using the tuptap with multi_queue.

My question is what causes this difference between memory consumption.
Thank you.

Comment: The really interesting question here is if you really intend to use thousands of TUN interfaces, and if yes, for what? (And I don't have an answer, but "multi_queue" sort of insinuates that it needs more memory to store the queues, so factor 100 doesn't surprise).

Comment: Hello dirkt, i thought so as well, however i noticed the memory gets consumed when u create the interfaces, not when we really create the fd for each such queue. So I am not sure if TUN interface is reserving the memory for max 256 queues right at inception.In the test above, i am simply creating them, haven't yet attached any userspace code to these interfaces yet. That aspect perplexes me.

Comment: I guess the simplest way to find out what gets allocated when is to read the kernel code ...

Comment: I guess so, sounds interesting read to me for a weekend.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand it now.
Today, when we we create multi_queue tun interface, kernel goes ahead and unconditionally creates 256 queues.
When we don't set the multi_queue flag only a single tx queue is created.